# Connect PS4 to VPN to hide IP

Tags: networking, vpn, ip-address, ps4

I have a PS4 console connected via LAN cable to a WiFi router. The WiFi router is connected to a Windows 10 PC also via LAN cable.

I am subscribed to a VPN service(Surfshark) and I am wondering if there is a way to connect my PS4 to the internet with my VPN, so that my IP address is hidden, like on my PC.

I have searched on Google but couldnt find a clear solution on how to do that.

-I tried sharing the VPN connection (in network adapter management) with the Ethernet connection, resulting on no internet access at all.

-Surfshark has a ''smart DNS'' feature for PS4 that does not act as a VPN but just change DNS settings, without hiding your IP address

-There is a VPN option in my router settings that uses OpenVPN, but again that does not seem to be what im looking for since they say to install OpenVPN on devices that I want to use to router built-in VPN with, wich is impossible to install anything on a PS4 console.

So I am confused on how to do so. Any tips or help would be really appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: who is `they say`? ... if you do some research about VPN, then you may come to realize that the router VPN is the answer to your problem ... if you already subscribe to a VPN service, then all you have to do, is to try it on your router

Comment: @jsotola Well the router instructions on how to setup the VPN feature

Comment: @jsotola there is only instructions on how to install OpenVPN , and on how to install OpenVPN client on Windows, MAC, iPhones and Androids. It is impossible to install a VPN client on a PS4.. so I think installing this would be a waste of time. Unless theres a part I dont understand

Comment: @jsotola Well you asked at first ''who is they say'' so I replied the router instructions on how to setup the VPN as ''who''

Comment: your VPN provider should have given you login credentials and an IP address for creating the VPN tunnel ... put those credentials (login/password) and the connection destination into your router config page ... the router should then log into your VPN provider server automatically ... you can confirm by navigating to https://whatsmyip.com/ with non-vpn connected device

Comment: In order to connect devices to your VPN you would have to connect your router to the VPN.  This would mean all internet traffic would be routed through the VPN.